# Blackberry tablet SDK on Win64

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to install the BlackBerry tablet SDK 0.9.0 for Windows but the installer gives the following error:

```
Win64 not supported.
The author of the package you are installing did not include support for this platform
```

Is there a way to trick the installer to think I have a 32-bit OS instead of a 64-bit one?

Comment: Have you tried running it in compatibility mode ?

Comment: Wow, not supporting 64-bit Windows is a pretty awful decision on RIM's part.

Comment: I've tried to run it in compatibility mode for WinXP SP3, but it produces the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this works for Windows 7 x64.

1. Install a java vm for "Windows" (aka the 32bit version from Oracle)
2. Reboot after install
3. Unzip the BlackBerryTabletSDK-Air-Installer-0.9.0-Win.exe installer file (I used 7zip)
4. Navigate to this file:
   BlackBerryTabletSDK-Air-Installer-0.9.0-Win\Windows\BlackBerryTabletSDK-Air-Installer-0.9.0.201010221500.lax
5. Locate this property:
   lax.nl.current.vm=
6. Set it to the location where you installed the 32 bit jvm (for me):
   lax.nl.current.vm=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java.exe
7. Save the file
8. Double click the BlackBerryTabletSDK-Air-Installer-0.9.0.201010221500.exe 6.